# Assign subclasses to each array element (run-time type)

Tags: java, arrays, types

I have a base class `Building` and subclasses `House` and `School`. I have declared an `array` of `Building` objects the following way. I am not sure how to assign subclasses to each array element (run time type).

```
Building[] House = new Building[3];
Building[] School = new School[2];
```

Comment: What issues are you running into? Are you getting compiler errors?

Comment: House ob = House[0]; & School obj = House[1];

Comment: Java's convention is to use `lowerCamelCase` for variables and `CamelCase` for classes. Following these conventions will make the code easier to work with for all developers.

Comment: Is `School` a variable name or a class name?  You're using it both different ways in the same statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `instanceof` to determine the subclass

```
if (building instanceof House) {
    House[0] = building;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are asking how to check types at runtime or to populate with types at runtime.  If the latter then see @Salah's answer using `instanceof`.  In particular, why the `House` array is being populated with `Building` objects while the `School` array is being populated with `School` objects is confusing me.

To assign:

```
Building[] house = new House[3];
Building[] school = new School[2];
```

You could also populate the array with `Building` objects and then use type checking when you need to down the road.